# Problem with uploadify jQuery and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, uploadify

So I'm using uploadify to upload multiple images to a folder.  Along with each upload, I want to pass along a 'batch name' from a text box value.

When I hard code the batch_name (Fire) below, the database updates fine, but when I replace 'fire' with $('#batch_name').val() the value doesn't seem to pass.

### javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#uploadify").uploadify({
        'uploader'       : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'         : 'uploadify.php',
        'scriptData'     : {'session_id': '<?php echo session_id(); ?>', 'batch_name': 'Fire'},
        'cancelImg'      : 'cancel.png',
        'queueID'        : 'fileQueue',
        'auto'           : false,
        'multi'          : true
    });
});
</script>
```

### textbox

```
<input type="text" name="batch_name" id="batch_name"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are grabbing the value of `batch_name` at `document.ready`, when (I'm guessing) the field is blank – the user hasn't had time to type a batch name when the DOM is first ready!  (`$('#batch_name').val()` is evaluated before making (and in order to make) the call to `.uploadify( ... )`, **not** when the upload is submitted.)

In order for Uploadify to pass a batch name typed in to a field, you need to change the `scriptData` object **before** the upload is submitted.

```
$('#uploadify').uploadifySettings('scriptData', { 'session_id': '<?php echo session_id(); ?>', 'batch_name': $('#batch_name').val() });
```